# Is there an equivalent "eval" function for swift, like there is in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, swift, eval

If not, how can I loop through IBOutlets (like temp1, temp2, temp3) and chance a property sequentially?

In matlab, I would concatenate a string and use eval.

```
for k = 1:3 
    eval(["temp",num2str(k)]);
end
```

I'm new to Swift, and want to do this with IBOutlets. Something like,

```
for(var k = 0, ++k, k==4) {
    eval(["self.temp",String(k),".backgroundcolor"]);
end
```

I know the eval function is in Matlab format, but I'm just expressing what I'd like to have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift is a static type language, so that it's impossible to implement something like "eval" in Matlab.
You can reach same behaviour with this code:

```
@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for label in labels {
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Although probably it is possible to do some magic using the runtime, connecting all the components in the same outlet collection is the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you. How do you populate "labels"? In other words, how do I add IBOutlets into this variable "labels"?

Comment: After creating the array

@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

using Interface Builder, you must connect each label to the Outlet Collections, like this: 

http://i62.tinypic.com/2074bd4.png

Comment: Programmatically? I have my IBOutlets declared. I've declared your suggested @IBOutlet var labels:[UILabel]!. I'm just confused about how to put the IBOutlets into the array so that I can use your for loop method of changing properties.

Comment: why programmatically? If you are using @IBOutlet you must use Interface Builder an linking them as in the previous screenshot...

I'm not sure I have correctly understood your question...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do eval in swift. See here:

https://github.com/johnno1962/InjectionIII/tree/master/EvalApp

Source code:
https://github.com/johnno1962/InjectionIII/blob/master/InjectionBundle/SwiftEval.swift