# Convert string to executable code in swift

Tags: swift, string, eval

I am trying execute code from string. Is some way in Swift5 executable simplified example in java:

```
eval("alert('Alive! Woo!')");
```

??

Comment: You could parse it and execute predefined functions. But I don't think it's possible to load Swift code from strings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372865/1271826.